# Spark cannot find SQL server jdbc driver even if both the mssql.jar and the .dll are present in the path

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to connect Spark to a SQL server using this:
#Myscript.py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example").config("spark.driver.extraClassPath","/home/mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre15.jar:/home/sqljdbc_auth.dll")\
    .getOrCreate()

sqldb = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://server:5150;databaseName=testdb;integratedSecurity=true") \
    .option("dbtable", "test_tbl") \
    .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") \
    .load()
sqldb.select('coldate').show()
```

I have made sure that both the .dll and the .jar is under /home folder. I call it like so:

```
spark-submit --jars /home/sqljdbc41.jar MyScript.py


py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o51.load.
: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:3462d79d-c165-4607-9790-67a2c786a9cf
```

Seems like it cannot find the .dll file? I ahve verified it exists under /home.

Answer (score 0):

This error was resolved when I placed the sqljdbc_auth.dll file in "C:\Windows\System32" folder.

For those who want to know where to find this dll file, you may:

1. Download the JDBC Driver for SQL Server (sqljdbc_6.0.8112.200_enu.exe) from the Microsoft website below:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774

2. Unzip it and navigate as follows:

   \Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_6.0\enu\auth\x64